# Calculate difference between dates for each unique ID and also based on another parameter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I'm quite a beginner with Excel and I've been stuck with the following problem.

I have the following table:

[image]

Spreadsheet available [here](https://file.io/t2QXXbVftNuG)

For each unique "Task ID" that shows up twice, I need to calculate the difference in hours between two dates, where one date corresponds to "Travel Details" and the other corresponds to "Client Sent For".

To further clarify with an example, let's take into consideration Task ID 2552804. This shows up twice (B3 and B8), therefore I want to calculate the time difference between D8 (that is on the row "Travel Details") and D3 (that is on the row "Client Sent For"). The results should be presented as two columns, one with each unique Task ID and one with the corresponding time difference.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do all of them have duplicates? What result do you expect if not? What if there is more than 2 duplicates? Do you want time difference in decimal? Also, you should post a data example easy to copy/paste so the community can help you out.

Comment: Thanks for helping :) Not all of them have duplicates, and when there isn't a duplicate I'm happy to get an empty field or a error, doesn't really matter. Also there won't be more than 2 duplicates as there will be at maximum one date for "Travel Details" and one for "Client Sent For". I'm not home right now but I'll post a data example later.